# Google Maps API V3 Places Library Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I'm using the Google Maps API V3 in Chrome, and I'm trying to use the Place library to add points of interest to my map. Except in the setMarker method, I'm getting an error from the following line `position: place.geometry.location` with the error `Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`. [Here is my code](http://paste.ofcode.org/anchA6WNRmPw4wtLFiijFS)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api_key&libraries=places&sensor=FALSE"></script>
```

Comment: I know, I've looked at tons of examples, at they're the same. I'm going to put the line where I call the API and the Places library (maybe somethings wrong there...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fim = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);
setMarker(fim);
```

...

```
setMarker(results[i]);
```

...

```
function setMarker(place) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: mapp,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });
}
```

You are using the `setMarker()` function to create markers from within the Places callback where you are passing the whole result object. But you pass a `LatLng` object to the same function where you do `setMarker(fim)`.

Instead of using the same function you can just do:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    map: mapp,
    position: fim
});
```

instead of `setMarker(fim);`

Comment: Is there a way to convert the `LatLng` object to the method so it works? So I don't have to create another `setMarker` function just for the `LatLng` objects...